# array is undefined in class file, but not in component.ts

Tags: angular, typescript

I am working on **Angular** application in which I'm validating a form using bootstrap validator. In this form we are using an **array of objects** to store key value pairs. This array is declared in a class file called *model.ts*, now to validate the form I need array to have at least one object. This array is showing the values in component.ts file but it's undefined in class file.

*model.ts*

```
public class className{
   public arrayofObjects:any=[];
   
   public validatorOptions?:{
     fields:{
       fieldName:{
          validators:{
            callback:{callback:function(validator){
                 return:{
                  valid:this.arrayofObjects.length>0,
                  message:''
                  }
             }}
          }
       }
     }
   }
}
```

---

component.ts

```
export class CreateComponent implements OnInit{
    object:className=new className();

    addObjectToArray(){
       let obj=getObject(); //get object 
       this.object.arrayofObject.push(obj);
    }

}
```

Comment: try to change `function(validator) { ... }` to `(validator) => { ... }`

Comment: stackOverflow never dissapoints. Thanks for help mate. It got solved